# Web-Shiro getSuccessUrl of PassThruAuthenticationFilter

Tags: authentication, shiro

I've used Shiro's inbuilt login behavior for sometime. The user is redirected to the login page when they try to access a protected resource, then after successful login, they are redirected back to the resource they were trying to access; that is, the successUrl property of PassThruAuthenticationFilter.

Now that I'm using my own custom login, I can't seem to find a way of getting this successUrl right. Below is shiro.ini configuration:

shiro.ini

```
[main]
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
authc.successUrl = /index.xhtml #index.xhtml is fallback url
```

Below is my login code

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(configFileDir + "shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
session = currentUser.getSession();
PassThruAuthenticationFilter filter = new PassThruAuthenticationFilter();
String url = filter.getSuccessUrl();
if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username,password);
    //
    //
    //
}
```

I know it does not make sense to use getSuccessUrl on a newly initiated PassThruAuthenticationFilter class, so I'm wondering, what's the correct way of getting the filter object?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the solution; I added the following lines in my login code:

```
import org.apache.shiro.web.util.WebUtils;
//...
String successUrl = WebUtils.getSavedRequest(request);
```

It worked like a charm. I din't have to worry about PassThruAuthenticationFilter anymore.

**Updated**

I found it from this [link](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Saved-Request-using-PassThruAuthenticationFilter-and-Spring-Controller-td7455645.html)

> Use the following from within your Spring MVC controller:
>
> import org.apache.shiro.web.util.WebUtils; ... String fallbackUrl =
>   "/path/to/go/to/incase/there/is/no/saved/request";
>   WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest(request, response, fallbackUrl);
>   return null; //tell Spring MVC not to render a view, we're redirecting
>   explicitly